# Matlab:How can i change a matrix of binary values [0 1] with 20% percentage or 30 % or 50 % M

Tags: matlab

using matlab, I like to change my matrix with binary values [0 1] with a percentage :

example:

Matrix = [ 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
           1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
           1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]

how can i change this matrix with a 20 % percentage or 30 % or x% percentage.

Thank you .

Comment: Can you please given an example of the desired output and some code you have already tried?

Comment: *"how can i change this matrix with a 20 % percentage"* what does this mean??? Do you want to change all the `1`s to `0.2`s or `20`s? Or are you just trying to make a matrix that has 20% `1`s and 80% `0`s with the `1` scattered randomly?

Comment: Exactly , my matrix is 10*10 , with 0 and 1 values , i would like to change my original matrix with a percentage , like 20 % , 30 %

Comment: As a suggestion, explain your problem/question better: If i am not mistaken you want to construct a boolean matrix (e.g. 10x10) with a fixed percentage of ones (E.g. 20,30 or x% of ones). Now give a minimal example .e.g. [1 0 0, 0 0 0, 0 1 1] would be a 3x3 matrix with 33% ones.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with using `randperm`-function to find indices and apply the `not()`-function on those indices, in order to change True to False and vice versa. If `x` is the percentage of the matrix, which shall be changed, the code could look like this:

```
Matrix = [ 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0];

% //find number and indices of matrix elements to change
x = 0.2; % relative percentage 
n = round(numel(Matrix)*x); % // num of elements to change
idx = randperm(numel(Matrix));
idx = idx(1:n); % // take the first n random indices

% // apply the change on elements
Matrix(idx) = not(Matrix(idx)); % // 0->1, 1->0 at indices idx
```

In order to see what happens, here comes an example, where `x=0.2` the we need to change `n=6` elements of your matrix

```
% Explanation in an example
idx % // [22    16    30    18     6    10]
Matrix_original(idx) % // [1     0     0     0     1     1]
Matrix(idx) % // [0     1     1     1     0     0]
```

So for those 6 indices all ones are now zeros and all zeros are now ones.

Comment: This will not yield 20% all the time. You are using random distribution meaning it could be only 15% of the values beeing smaller than 0.2 but also 30%. This does more or less the job but it aint exact.

Comment: @TheMinion Yep, i noticed that, too. I just fixed it that it now always "exactly" changes x percent, if possible. Otherwise the closed number of elements to change will be set.

Comment: @TheMinion forgot to change that variable, yes. It does work now. The ``idx=idx(1:n)`` is used in order to get the first ``n`` random linear indices of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
matr= zeros(10);
ratio= 20;
No_of_ones=round(numel(matr)/100*ratio);
No_of_zeros=numel(matr)-No_of_ones;
helper=[ones(No_of_ones,1);zeros(No_of_zeros,1)];
new_order= randperm(numel(matr));
new_matr=helper(new_order);
matr= reshape(new_matr,size(matr,1),size(matr,2));
```

matr: is the matrix (in this case 10x10)
 
ratio: is the ratio in percent. 
 
Then I compute the number of zeros and ones. I construct a 1-dim array with the exact number of ones and zeros (rounding the 1 if the ratio is not a divider of your number of elements) Before bringing them into a random order with `randperm`. 
 
Last but not least I reshape them to the desired output (10x10).